# Yocto: Build custom bootloaders outside aarch64-poky-linux work directory

Tags: yocto, bootloader, openembedded

I have a project that is mostly complete for a custom third party SoM which requires custom bootstrap/bootloaders, currently the recipe is in a meta-bsp layer which works alright however they are built in the aarch64-poky-linux build directory. We have multiple SoM models from this manufacturer that each require different bootloader configs and I'd like them to be built in a machine specific non-linux directory if possible like aarch64-<machine>-none or something. Is this possible?

We are using dunfell release.

Recipes are in meta-mfg/recipes-bsp/mfg-/mfg-_version.bb
Fairly standard recipe setup including:

```
    SECTION = "bootloaders"
    SRC_URI..
    DEPENDS (native packages only)
    do_configure()
    do_compile()
    do_install()
```

Current build directory: tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mfg-bootloader/1.x.x-rx/ 
Preferred build directory: tmp/work/aarch64-<machine>-none/mfg-bootloader/1.x.x-rx/

When building for different machines/soms it uses the same directory and uses the previous build which may be incorrect. We do have a workaround where we don't stamp the configure/build/install tasks so they always rebuild however we'd like a cleaner more appropriate implementation.

Is there any way to accomplish this?
I haven't been able to find any information so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have been pointed to the solution from the IRC channel for anyone with the same question:
Add `PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"` to the recipe to build in machine specific folders.